# What if block N were based not on N-1 but on both N-2 and N-3?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, blockchain-fork

If the bitcoin protocol were changed so that the merkle root from block N-1 were replaced in block N by the two roots of blocks N-2 and N-3, then it would become possible to mine 2 blocks at a time in parallel and increase the block frequency compared to the time each block took to propagate. Each block would still get confirmed by 6 of the following 7 blocks. The block size variance could be controlled by requiring that transactions with odd hashes go into odd-numbered blocks and vice-versa. What would be the limitations of this variant protocol compared to the existing Bitcoin protocol, assuming nobody considered one confirmation to be much better than zero?

Comment: I don't think I understand your proposal. There are five fields in a Bitcoin block header: version, prevblock, merkle root, timestamp, and nonce. Which one are you proposing to modify, and how?

Comment: prevblock, by replacing it with two fields based on blocks N-2 and N-3.

Answer (score 1):

Objections that come to mind initially, I'm sure there are more:

1. You don't want to split the hashing power into two halves because that would make it easier for an adversary to get 51% of that halve: 25% of the total or even less if the halves are not exactly 50-50.

   The idea behind Proof of Work is to concentrate as much work as possible behind one and the same chain and make that the level-to-beat by an attacker.
2. If you force odd transactions into odd blocks (and vice versa) then you still have 10 minutes block times for all transactions.